# Search for matching lines and combind the output on a single line

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to search for three lines on the format `"\d+ [xyz]{3} \d+"` in a text file and output the lines on a single line using sed.

---

Example input:

```
... 
33 xxx 7
...
33 zzz 3
...
33 yyy 5
...
```

Output:

```
33 7 3 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[xyz]{3}$/ && $3 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {
    num = $1
    digits = digits " " $3
}

END {
    print num digits
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
text 
33 xxx 7
more text
33 zzz 3
55 n
33 yyy 5
66 asf sdf
```

Run the script:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

And output:

```
33 7 3 5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way with `sed`:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## Subbtitute line that matches the format with both numbers.
s/^\([0-9]\+\) [xyz]\{3\} \([0-9]\+\)$/\1 \2/ 

## If substitution succeed, go to label 'a'.
ta

## If substitution failed, go to label 'b'.
bb

## Save content to 'hold space'.
:a
H

## In last line, get content from 'hold space', remove numbers
## not needed in output and print.
:b
$ {
    g   
    s/^\n//
    s/\n[0-9]\+//g
    p   
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
text 
33 xxx 7
more text
33 zzz 3
55 n
33 yyy 5
66 asf sdf
```

Run the script:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

And output:

```
33 7 3 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^\([0-9]\+ \)[xyz]\{3\} \([0-9]\+\)/{s//\1\2/;H};$!d;g;s/.//;s/\n[0-9]*//g' file
33 7 3 5
```